# Replace column values in an SQL query without updating the original table

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following `observation` table:

```
|country |
|:-------|
|spain   |
|france  |
|france  |
|usa     |
|france  |
|france  |
|france  |
|spain   |
|spain   |
|usa     |
```

I want to translate them in the query, without updating the original table, using the following `translation` table:

```
|source |fr         |en     |
|:------|:----------|:------|
|france |France     |France |
|usa    |Etats-Unis |USA    |
|spain  |Espagne    |Spain  |
```

I'm aware of the `UPDATE/SET` verbs, but the issue is that (as far as I know) it replaces the original table, and I just want the column to be transformed in the result, without modifying the original table.

In other words, I'm looking for a SQL query that would output:

```
|country    |
|:----------|
|Espagne    |
|France     |
|France     |
|Etats-Unis |
|France     |
|France     |
|France     |
|Espagne    |
|Espagne    |
|Etats-Unis |
```

But without modifying the `observation` table.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why there's a column `en` within the table `translation` ?

Comment: I want to either translate in English or in French depending on what the user needs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a join:

```sql
SELECT t.fr AS country
FROM observation o
INNER JOIN translation t
    ON t.source = o.country;
```